# jQuery ZendX setup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, zendx

I am trying to test if jQuery is working in my application I have the following in my bootstrap:

bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
protected function _initView()
{
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
$view->headTitle('IMR - BI System');
$view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;
$view->baseUrl = Zend_Registry::get('config')->root_path;

$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
$view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css');
$view->jQuery()->setLocalPath($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
$view->jQuery()->setUiLocalPath($view->baseUrl .'/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js');
$view->jQuery()->enable();
$view->jQuery()->uiEnable();
$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

return $view;
}
}
```

and then this in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", '', array('defaultDate' => date('Y/m/d', time()))); ?>
```

and I get the text box but with the following error -> http://pastebin.com/7Hv7d2Qf

also in the bootstrap file I had to take the following line out:

```
 $view->baseUrl = Zend_Registry::get('config')->root_path;
```

otherwise i got this error -> http://pastebin.com/tde4J7L1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this method above your _initView method

```
public function _initSetup()
    {
        Zend_Registry::set('config', new Zend_Config($this->getOptions()));

    }
```

And in your application.ini add this line

```
 phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

If you are using layout then do this in your layout.phtml otherwise paste it above your datepicker

```
<?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
```

Comment: now my application loads but I get the error message above the site -> http://pastebin.com/MdLnXAjt and the textbox shows but no jqeury date picker.

Comment: Ok so this gets rid of the error, but the date picker doesn't work.. as it can't find the css files and js files. The paths are correct though.. These are the paths copy and pasted from the finder -> /public/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css & /public/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js. What am I doing wrong.